# Всем привет. Подскажите как реализовать List map String Integer.?

Tags: java, map, java-hashmap

```
public class Person {
    private int id;
    private String firstName;

    public Person(int id, String firstName) {
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Person)) return false;
        Person person = (Person) o;
        return id == person.id && Objects.equals(firstName, person.firstName);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, firstName);
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }


}
public class MapExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person first = new Person(1, "A");
        Person second = new Person(2, "B");
        Person third = new Person(3, "C");

        Map<Integer, Person> map = new HashMap<>();//инициализация hashMap
        map.put(first.getId(), first);//положили в мапу
        map.put(second.getId(), second);//положили в мапу
        map.put(third.getId(), third);//положили в мапу
```

Comment: `List<Map<String, Integer>>`?

Comment: Тоесть вместо мапы которая есть я инициализирую List<Map<String, Integer>> ???

Comment: Вопрос был `List map String Integer`, как я понял вы хотели список из словарей, где ключом строка, а значением число

Comment: Поясню. У меня задание вывести напечатать ключи со значением"abc"  в Map<String, integer> я это вроде сделал. Теперь задание  тоже самое только с List<Map<String, Integer>>

Comment: Совершенно не понятна задача и как заголовок соотносится с фрагментом кода.

Comment: Уже все решено спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример заполнения список словарями и перебора списка словарей для нахождения определенного ключа

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        List<Map<String, Integer>> items = new ArrayList<>();
        items.add(new HashMap<String, Integer>() {{
            put("abc", 123);
        }});
        items.add(new HashMap<String, Integer>() {{
            put("hello", 999);
            put("abc", 999);
        }});
        items.add(new HashMap<String, Integer>() {{
            put("abc", 777);
        }});
        System.out.println(items);
        // [{abc=123}, {abc=999, hello=999}, {abc=777}]

        for (Map<String, Integer> map : items) {
            if (map.containsKey("abc")) {
                System.out.println(map.get("abc"));
            }
        }
```

Результат:

```
123
999
777
```